# Unable to add callback function directly to the click event of JSX child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I'm currently trying to build youtube clone. I'm trying to manipulate states with callback functions passed from parent component to child components.
 But the issues is that I am unable to assign my callback function directly to the click event of my child JSX component.

I'm passing a callback function from Parent component, APP to child component, VideoList and then again to VideoListItem. The issues is in VideoListItem. If I add callback function from App directly to JSX like this `onClick={onVideoSelect(video)}` , it causes infinite loop and throws Error Message "Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.".

But if I add callback function like this `onClick={()=> onVideoSelect(video)}`, it works. I want to understand why this error is happening and underlaying concept.

Here is my index.js

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';
// create a new component.That should produce some html

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyBem7NlPNdK50NStTS4MJDlXBaiRDfI1U0'



class App extends Component  {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            videos:[],
            selectedVideo: null
        }
        YTSearch(
            { key:API_KEY , term:'spaceart'},
            videos => {
                console.log("Videos Download ::"+videos.length)

                this.setState({
                    videos:videos,
                    selectedVideo:videos[0]
                })
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
    return(
            <div>
            <SearchBar/>
            <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo} />
            <VideoList onVideoSelect = { selectedVideo => this.setState({selectedVideo}) } videos={this.state.videos} />
            </div>
        );
    }


}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector('.container'));
```

video_list.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

const VideoList = (props)=>{

    const videoComponents = props.videos.map(
        (video) => {
            return <VideoListItem onVideoSelect={props.onVideoSelect} key={video.etag} video={video} />
        }
    )

return (
    <div><ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
    {videoComponents}
    </ul></div>
    );
}

export default VideoList;
```

video_list_item.js

```
   import React from 'react';

    const VideoListItem = ({video,onVideoSelect}) => {

        console.log("Enter video list Item");

        return (
            <li onClick={onVideoSelect(video)} className="list-group-item">
                <div cl

 1. List item

assName="video-list media">
                <div className="media-left">
                <img className="media-object" src={video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url } />
           </div>
           <div className="media-body">
                <div className="media-heading">{video.snippet.title} </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
           </li> 
            );
    }

    export default VideoListItem;
```

Comment: you need to bind it to the component

Comment: we need to assign a function to onClick, `onClick={e => onVideoSelect(video)}`

Comment: why can't I assign directly like that ' onClick={onVideoSelect(video)} ' ?

Comment: post the `VideoList` component

Comment: Thanks.Post is edited and VideoList is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add parenthesis `()` to a function, it is executed. So, this line

`onClick={onVideoSelect(video)}`

causes the function to execute as soon as this line is encountered. Inside this function you are calling setState, so the state updates and triggers render method which then again executes your `onVideoSelect` method and it forms a cycle.
You need to pass to onClick, a reference of a function. When the click event happens, onClick executes the function you passed to it.

`onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video)}`

Comment: Thanks.Your explanation is clean and easy to understand.